# How do I count over an array given an offset?

Tags: php, arrays, count

If I have array `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]` and I'm at letter c which is index 2.
I'm trying to figure out how to get the letter that is on offset 21, in this scenario I would loop to the beginning of the array and keep counting the result would return letter d.
Or if I was on letter f with offset 1 it would return letter g.
How can I do this? I can't figure it out.

Comment: show us your try first and then ask for help. Sorry to say we're here to help you, not to code for you sir :).

Comment: If starting at 2 and offsetting by 21 you'd get 23 which is 3 mod 10 (where 10 is the array size). Is this the question?

Comment: @apokryfos i believe so, i think modulo was the operator i've been looking for. Where are you getting 3 from?

Comment: Mod is what's left after even divisions. 2 % 5 is 1, because 2 goes into 5 twice, with a remainder of 1.

Comment: 23 = 3 mod 10 means that if you do an integer division 23/10 you get some value X (here X=2) and a remainder of 3. What you have seems similar to a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)

Comment: @JoelHager I think you mean `5 % 2 = 1`

Comment: @apokryfos I'm still confused on this. What's the formula? I keep getting different results.

Comment: You might want to help us a bit more by sharing some more code that you're having trouble with.

Comment: @apokryfos so the formula is `((index+offset)%array_size)%array_size` ?

Comment: @apokryfos @apokryfos Ah! yes! I got the correct answer with `((index+offset)%array_size)%array_size`. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry - I was trying to type on my phone and got it backward. Yes you are right nick.

Comment: `((index+offset)%array_size)` should be the same as `((index+offset)%array_size)%array_size` since `((index+offset)%array_size)` will always result in a number less than `array_size` so that number % array size is the same number